# Qt Udp socket data handling

Tags: c++, c, qt, sockets, udp

I have two applications that running on the same pc.First sends data on udp with Qt sockets with 3 threads from 3 different ports.Second application listens the ports and gives me the output.But when I firstly start the program it gives me all the true data.If I close it and restart it gives data but this time it is not true.But if I restart computer the program again works well.I thought that is an udp socket flush issue.SO I flush them at the program starts to run?What can be the solution?

Comment: what is "not true data" ? Can you please clarify this?

Comment: @piotrus the data is a point in an image

Comment: so "not true data" means wrong numbers, wrong order of incoming messages or something else?

Comment: yes @piotruś you are right

Comment: It is coming in wrong order with correct values, right?

Comment: yes @piotrus it is true.I think the buffer must be flushed or something.am i true?

Comment: are you aware that UDP is unreliable and this is one of the implications that may result?